# Why my auth0 token expires when refreshing page or clicking link in my Angular app?

Tags: angular, authentication, token, auth0

I'm setting up authentication in my Angular SPA.

I'm using auth0 and I was going through a tutorial on their page: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2

I did login tutorial.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as auth0 from 'auth0-js';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  userProfile: any;

  private _idToken: string;
  private _accessToken: string;
  private _expiresAt: number;

    auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    clientID: '*****',
    domain: '****',
    responseType: 'token id_token',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/callback',
    scope: 'openid profile'
  });

  constructor(public router: Router) {
    this._idToken = '';
    this._accessToken = '';
    this._expiresAt = 0;
  }

  public login(): void {
    this.auth0.authorize();
  }

  public handleAuthentication(): void {
    this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
      if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
        window.location.hash = '';
        this.localLogin(authResult);
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      } else if (err) {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }

  public getProfile(cb): void {
    if (!this._accessToken) {
      throw new Error('Access Token must exist to fetch profile');
    }

    const self = this;
    this.auth0.client.userInfo(this._accessToken, (err, profile) => {
      if (profile) {
        self.userProfile = profile;
      }
      cb(err, profile);
    });
  }

  private localLogin(authResult): void {

    localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', 'true');

    const expiresAt = (authResult.expiresIn * 1000) + new Date().getTime();
    this._accessToken = authResult.accessToken;
    this._idToken = authResult.idToken;
    this._expiresAt = expiresAt;
  }

  public renewTokens(): void {
    this.auth0.checkSession({}, (err, authResult) => {
      if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
        this.localLogin(authResult);
      } else if (err) {
        alert(`Could not get a new token (${err.error}: ${err.error_description}).`);
        this.logout();
      }
    });
  }

  public logout(): void {
    this._accessToken = '';
    this._idToken = '';
    this._expiresAt = 0;

    localStorage.removeItem('isLoggedIn');
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }

  public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    return new Date().getTime() < this._expiresAt;
  }

  get accessToken(): string {
    return this._accessToken;
  }

  get idToken(): string {
    return this._idToken;
  }


}
```

I click login on my page, I'm successful, I got token and everything is fine. But when I refresh the page or click a link is getting logged out. What should I do to stay logged in the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you are saving the data in the in-memory variable. So, when you reload the application, the in-memory variable (**_expiresAt**) lost the value. Therefore, **isAuthenticated()** method returns **false**. You can save the data in the browser **localStorage**.

```
 private localLogin(authResult): void {
      const expiresAt = JSON.stringify(
      authResult.expiresIn * 1000 + new Date().getTime()
    );

    localStorage.setItem("access_token", authResult.accessToken);
    localStorage.setItem("id_token", authResult.idToken);
    localStorage.setItem("expires_at", expiresAt);
  }
```

Then, in the **isAuthenticated()** method, you can load the expiresAt from the localStorage.

```
  public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    const expiresAt = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("expires_at") || "{}");
    return new Date().getTime() < expiresAt;
  }
```

During the log out, you need to clear the data from localStorage.

```
public logout(): void {
    // Remove tokens and expiry time from localStorage
    localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
    localStorage.removeItem("id_token");
    localStorage.removeItem("expires_at");
    // Remove server SSO session
    this.auth0.logout({ returnTo: "http://localhost:4200" });

  }
```

Best Practice:

For SPA, follow auth0 best practice: https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens#single-page-apps

Comment: Thank you, that i was looking for. But is it safe to keep this tokens in localstorage?

Comment: there are some arguments around it. Auth0 does not recommend to store the token in the localStorage or sessionStorage for SPA. Because any data stored can be accessed through the javascript and vulnerable to cross-site scripting. @K4mczi

Comment: Ok, you are really helpful, I think better solution will be do auth0 in java backend

Comment: @TanverHasan they recommend to don't store it. Suggesting to use regular webapp, but clearly not clear to how use it with angular. Have you a sample ?

Comment: @MathKimRobin the new SDK auth0-spa-js provides better mechanism for storing the token, if the token is lost, you can obtain a new token by using silent authentication. https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spa-js