# Application using Auth0 going to login page on refresh

Tags: javascript, authentication, identity, auth0

My simple application written in Javascript is using a service (which is written as a wrapper on Auth0) for authentication. On successful login, if I refresh the home page, application again goes to login page (even if I have stored the access token in cookies)

I also tried to store the access token in browser session storage.

As my index.html is launched, i am checking if my application url contains access token. If there is no access token, I redirect it to login page.

```
if (((window.location.hash).indexOf('access_token') < 0)) {
            location.replace(redirectUrl);
}
```

On successful login, as url has access token in it, app works fine further.
But next time when I refresh the home page, it don't have access token in URL.

As per my understanding, as I have access token in cookies, it should not ask me for login again as long as token is valid.

1. It is still asking for login. What should be the strategy should I use to persist the token ?
2. On logout, I am setting the cookie to expire. Is there any ideal way to do log out other than this?

Answer (score 0):

This can often be troubleshooted with a HAR file capture to follow the trail being left in the authentication flow. However since we don't have that option at this juncture here are a couple things to look at.

- Are you using Dev keys in your auth scenario?
- Expiry time
- Where is the access token being stored?
- https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/overview-access-tokens

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you have a somewhat incomplete implementation.

> As per my understanding, as I have access token in cookies, it should not ask me for login again as long as token is valid.

Saving token in the cookie storage and local storage does not have any relation with user authentication state. It is just a way of persisting the token and reading the data.  In each navigation, you need to read the token and extract the information from the token to make sure user is authenticated.

The architecture you should follow:

- Redirect the user to /authorize endpoint if there is no valid token in the application.
- Once auth0 finish the user validation, the user will be redirected in the whitelisted callback URL. Make sure this URL is unique and save the token from URL fragments. It is very important to complete the token validation on the client side. Otherwise, it will be a major security issue. https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/guides/id-token/validate-id-token
- Redirect the user to the secured URL.

I would highly recommend using auth0 SDK as it mitigates all the security issues including token signature validation using RS256 algorithm. 
https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vanillajs/01-login

You may find folloiwng thread useful
[Why my auth0 token expires when refreshing page or clicking link in my Angular app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55324666/why-my-auth0-token-expires-when-refreshing-page-or-clicking-link-in-my-angular-a/55328446#55328446)